# Why structure member seems to have an overflown value?

Tags: c, struct, structure, padding, bit

In the code below, I get A = -1 as output. I guess, it's because I am overflowing the A-member which is of 3 bits. 
I have two questions in this regard:

1. Shouldn't the compiler consider the last 3 bits and ignore the rest, for the member A? Why is the value negative ?
2. If all the bits are considered, why do I get the value of B = 0 as output?

I was expecting A would be having a value of 7 but I am clearly misunderstanding something. Please help.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
  char A: 3;
  char B: 3;
  char C: 3;
}my_struct;
my_struct new_object = {0};

void main(void)
{
  new_object. A = 63;
  printf("A = %d\n", new_object.A);
  printf("B = %d\n", new_object.B);
}
```

Comment: Isn't assigning 63 to A undefined behavior? So the outcome could be anything.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana: No it isn't. It isn't as `char c = 0xffff;` isn't. Thanks to C's Implicit Conversion.

Comment: @alk: Thanks for the information. I didn't know bit fields were included in integer conversions.

Answer (score 3):

> I was expecting A would be having a value of 7

OK.  7 is 111 in binary.  But you have a *signed* char (apparently, because you told us it came out as -1).  So you need to do:

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned char A: 3;
  unsigned char B: 3;
  unsigned char C: 3;
}my_struct;
```

Comment: Thanks. Making it as unsigned does gives me a value of 7 for A. However, I am now confused that why does it gives me a value of -1 when unsigned isn't written. Shouldn't I be getting a value of -3, since it is of 3 bits. The most significant bit can be for sign, and the rest two bits, should be set? Shouldn't this happen?
I am using the compiler present on the link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: `111` in two's-complement binary is -4 + 2 + 1 which is indeed -1.  Everything is as expected.  -3 would be 101.

Comment: Oops! Thanks John. I totally forgot that negative is stored in 2's complement. Stupid Me. Sorry

Comment: No problem.  There are only 10 kinds of people in the world: those who understand binary and those who do not.